# Why global value doesn't change when reading from another module?

Tags: python, module, global

I have three files:

globals.py:

```
value = None
```

reader.py:

```
from globals import *

def read_global():
    print(value)
```

changer.py:

```
from globals import *
from reader import *

def change_global():
    global value
    value = 1


change_global()
read_global()
```

I would expect the call to "read_global" would print 1, but the value None is printed.

Why is that the case? Why the new value set in "change_global" doesn't print?

Comment: Can you try to do `from reader import read_global` instead an retry?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been reading about modules in the Python documentation and it states:

> Each module has its own private symbol table, which is used as the global symbol table by all functions defined in the module. Thus, the author of a module can use global variables in the module without worrying about accidental clashes with a user’s global variables. On the other hand, if you know what you are doing you can touch a module’s global variables with the same notation used to refer to its functions, modname.itemname.

This implicates that the global symbol table is not shared between modules.

Answer (score 1):

Change your import into

changer.py:

```
from reader import *
import globals as g


def change_global():
    g.value = 1


change_global()
read_global()
print(g.value)
```

reader.py:

```
import globals as g

def read_global():
    print(g.value)
```

globals.py:

```
value = None
```

I think when you call value in the change_global function you are not calling the global variable you declare in `global.py` but creating new local variable inside the function so when you set the import alias into `g` will make sure you call/set the right one (variable)

Comment: I hope that's answer your question

Comment: Well, that works, and is a good solution but I'm looking for an explanation why can't I use  the "global variable" way of doing things.